# Ошибка 500 readbean

Tags: php, sql

[image]

Загрузил файлы на хостинг.При попытке зайти на страницу файла singup.php выдаёт ошибку 500.

Лог браузера:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` - добавьте эти три надстройки в самый вверх страницы, загрузите, обновите сайт и прочтите что за ошибка будет

Comment: InDevX,тоже самое

Comment: Смотрите логи сервера.

Comment: @BlackDark, Попробуйте с помощью file_exists, проверить наличие подключаемых файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Без логов можно сказать, что варианта тут 2.

1) На сервере нет файла db.php

Замените `require`на `include`

2) Версия php меньше 5.4, поэтому не поддерживаются массивы `$arr = []`

Замените `$arr = []` на `$arr =`array()`

Comment: А чем поможет замена require, include?))) Мне просто интересно...

Comment: https://vk.cc/ai9TeX Разница в том, что если файла нет, include вызовет ошибку уровня E_WARNING, a require - E_COMPILE_ERROR

Comment: И как это должно помочь? Если 500, это внутренняя ошибка сервера...

Comment: Ну так ошибка E_COMPILE_ERROR - фатальная ошибка, из-за которой сервер ответит ошибкой 500. Почитайте про классификацию ошибок: https://habr.com/ru/post/161483/

Comment: Да мне то читать не нужно, но дело в том что 500 вернётся только в случае если включёна директива display_errors.